# UI test broken in SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, xcuitest, gui-testing

I'm adding UI tests to my swiftUI app.

So far I haven't found any problem. But now I'm having problems testing a specific view (we will call it "MyCustomDetailView"). None of its components seem to be found so I added a log for XCUIApplication().debugDescription and the element tree seems empty:

```
    t =    50.00s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 30896
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 'com.sample.myapp'
```

I've tried to do some research in the accessibility of that view. It seems correct and if I enable voiceover it reads the view. So I've decide to comment each subview of this view and I finally found the one that is causing problems. Is this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyCustomBlock: View {
    
    var items: [Any]
    var clickOnItemAction: ([Any]) -> Void
    var seeAllAction: () -> Void
    var height: CGFloat = 0
    var hasMoreThanLimit = false
    var itemsCountInBlock = 0
    let limit = 6

    init(items: [Any],
         clickOnItemAction: @escaping ([Any]) -> Void,
         seeAllAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        self.items = items
        self.clickOnItemAction = clickOnItemAction
        self.seeAllAction = seeAllAction
        self.hasMoreThanLimit = self.items.count > limit
        self.height = CGFloat(Constants.mycustomblock.height)
        self.itemsCountInBlock = self.items.count > limit ? limit : self.items.count

        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            Text("BLOCK TITLE".localized)
                .font(.uibook16)
                .foregroundColor(Color("primary3_primary2"))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.bottom, 24)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack {
                    ForEach(0..<itemsCountInBlock, id: \.self) { index in
                    
                        let item = items[index] as? [Any]
                        let itemName = item?[1] as? String ?? ""
                        CustomDetailItemCell(itemName: itemName, width: 0) {
                            if let item = item {
                                clickOnItemAction(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: height)
            .padding(.bottom, self.hasMoreThanLimit ? 16 : 8)
            
            if self.hasMoreThanLimit {
                
                Button {
                    seeAllAction()
                } label: {
                    let message = "\("YOU HAVE MORE THAN".localized) 6 \("ITEMS. WATCH ALL".localized) \(items.count)"
                    Text(message)
                        .font(.uibold18)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("primary1_secondary3"))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've commented ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) and  LazyHStack lines this way:

```
//           ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
//                LazyHStack {
                    ForEach(0..<itemsCountInBlock, id: \.self) { index in
                    
                        let item = items[index] as? [Any]
                        let itemName = item?[1] as? String ?? ""
                        CustomDetailItemCell(itemName: itemName, width: 0) {
                            if let item = item {
                                clickOnItemAction(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
//                }
//            }
//            .frame(height: height)
//            .padding(.bottom, self.hasMoreThanLimit ? 16 : 8)
```

The block is shown with a wrong design (obviously) but the  XCUIApplication() element tree shows a lot of components and the UI test passes.

To add more confusion, this view (MyCustomBlock) is used in several views of my app, some of them with UI tests and all of them work and passes their tests without problems. But this MyCustomDetailView view is the only one that breaks with the UI tests. I could paste the whole code of this view, but it's large and it has nothing strange at a first glance. The block is used this way:

```
struct MainDetailView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    
                    ... // Navigation links

                    ScrollView {
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    
 
                            ... // Other custom blocks

                            if observedModel.items.count > 0 {
                                
                                MyCustomBlock(items: observedModel.items) { item in

                                    if let itemId = item[0] as? String,
                                       let itemIdInt = Int32(itemId) {

                                        selectedIndex = itemIdInt
                                        hasToGoToItemDetail = true
                                    }
                                } seeAllAction: {
                                    hasToGoToSeeAllItems = true
                                }
                                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 25)
                                .padding(.bottom, 24)
                            }

                           ... // Other custom blocks

                        }
                        .background(Color("primary4_primary3"))
                    }
                    .background(VStack(spacing: .zero) { Color("grey20_secondary4"); Color("primary4_primary3") })

                    Spacer()
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .background(Color("primary4_primary3"))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
 }
```

What could I check?